# jquery very simple plugin, very basic

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we call jquery plugin like this?
 this is in my plugin file

```
    (function($) {

    $.fn.alertme=function(){
    alert('just testing');
    };


    }(jQuery));
```

i have included the plugin file ,, and calling the function on my home page...

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {

    alertme();
    });


    </script>
```

I see an error message on console log `Uncaught ReferenceError: alertme is not defined` i even tried `return alert('just testing');` ,, how do we fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the function to `$.fn`, which is an alias to the prototype of the jQuery constructor. That means your function is attached to all objects created as `$(someArgs)`.

Call your function on a jQuery object, for example

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(document).alertme();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $({}).alertme();
});
```

or even

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $().alertme();
});
```

But there's no point in making a jQuery plugin if you don't use `this` (the jQuery object) in the function. Usually you'd do something like this :

```
// logs all elements of the jQuery collection
$.fn.logme=function(){
  this.each(function(){
    console.log(this);
  })
};

$(document).ready( function() {
   $('p').logme();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call using jQuery object

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(document).alertme();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgMSd/6/)